# Are there any ways to generate Scala code from Protobuf files in a Maven build?

Tags: scala, maven, protocol-buffers

I'm looking for a solution that includes all 3 of these things.  Thus far, I've been able to find Maven plugins that will generate Java code from proto files during a build, and command line tools that will generate Scala code from proto files, but nothing that mixes everything together.

The most promising thing I've found so far is ScalaBuff, and the fact that it exists in the Maven repos.  If I add it as a dependency thusly...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sandrogrzicic</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalabuff-compiler_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sandrogrzicic</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalabuff-runtime_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

...is there any way to simply have the Maven build launch it as a command line util during a phase of the build?  (hopefully generate-sources)  I also found this, but am at a loss as to how to get these to play nicely together: Maven: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Note: I'd really like this to be portable and not depend on something installed on my local box, but hacks are perfectly welcome (i.e. adding a jar or executable to source control)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

In addition to the above dependency, if I add the following...

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>protobuf-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>net.sandrogrzicic.scalabuff.compiler.ScalaBuff</mainClass>
            <arguments>
                <argument>--proto_path=src/main/protobuf</argument>
                <argument>--scala_out=target/generated-sources/scalabuff</argument>
            </arguments>
            <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/scalabuff</sourceRoot>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

...I can generate source during my build (in the generate-sources phase), but the build halts immediately after running the exec plugin for some reason.  So close!  If anyone can fix that last problem, this will be solved.

Comment: I don't suppose sbt is acceptable?  https://github.com/gseitz/sbt-protobuf/tree/scalabuff  ... you could configure Maven to launch an sbt build if you really wanted to stick with Maven.

Comment: I have to stick with Maven - it isn't a choice.  It still seems like it should be possible to have Maven invoke the ScalaBuff compiler using the exec plugin, but I suppose I could also try to have Maven invoke a barebones SBT build to use that plugin.

Comment: Please could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted? I agree that  the `exec` plugin is the correct fix here, as you have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: The maven exec plugin java goal doesn't fork, so the exit(0) in the scalabuff compiler was causing the whole build to exit. Also had to create a directory before generate-sources to keep ScalaBuff happy. Using the ScalaBuff dependencies and the following plugins actually works!:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="target/generated-sources/scalabuff" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>protobuf-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>-classpath</argument>
          <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
           also adding the project build directory -->
          <classpath/>
          <argument>net.sandrogrzicic.scalabuff.compiler.ScalaBuff</argument>
            <argument>--proto_path=src/main/protobuf</argument>
            <argument>--scala_out=target/generated-sources/scalabuff</argument>
        </arguments>
        <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/scalabuff</sourceRoot>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you have an example project on github that uses this you might share?